# Guaranteed write a member variable value to memory without marking it volatile

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following class:

```
public class Example {

    private AtomicBoolean isValueSet = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private int value = 0; // I DON'T want to make this volatile.

    private void initializeValue(int value) {
        // as you can see, value can only ever be set once.
        if (isValueSet.compareAndSet(false, true)) { 
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The `Example` class has a value which is initialised only **ONCE**, but **MUST** be initialised **AFTER** the instance of `Example` is created. This means I cannot set it in the constructor (make it `final`). `Example.value` is a write-once, read-many member variable.

**The issue:**

I am working in a multithreaded environment, so it is plausible that the value could be initialised on `Thread 1` and read on `Thread 2`. This means that after the value has been set on `Thread 1`, it is possible that the write hasn't been flushed from the cache to memory meaning that write is not visible to `Thread 2`.

Before you read any further, **I want to make is clear that the concern of this question is not any race conditions that might be present**, but simply ensuring that the `initializeValue()` call ensures the value is written to memory.

Although it is the simplest solution, I am working in a multithreaded environment where performance is key so I do **NOT** want to make `Example.value` `volatile`.

**Question:**

Now my understanding of the happens-before principle means that any values that are set within a `synchronized` block are automatically flushed to memory, so I could solve my problem with the following changes:

```
private void initializeValue(int value) {
    // as you can see, value can only ever be set once.
    if (isValueSet.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        synchronized (new Object()) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this correct?

---

**EDIT:**

Given we have established that the above does not work, does the following:

```
public class UnsafeUtil {

    private static final Unsafe unsafe;

    static {
        try {
            Field field = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            unsafe = (sun.misc.Unsafe) field.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void setValue(Object instance, String fieldName, Object value) {
        try {
            Field field = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            unsafe.putObjectVolatile(instance, unsafe.objectFieldOffset(field), value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}


public class Example {

    private AtomicBoolean isValueSet = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private Object value = null;

    private void initializeValue(Object value) {
        // as you can see, value can only ever be set once.
        if (isValueSet.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            UnsafeUtil.setValue(this, "value", value);
        }
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that is not correct. `synchronized` on a random object is pointless. Both reads and writes have to happen within a `synchronized` block on the same object (or on a `volatile` read/write of the same variable). Your issue with `volatile` seems misinformed. It's the right tool for the job here.

Comment: Your synchronized block is not quite synchronized, it locks on different objects for each thread.

Comment: You're going to have to make `value` `volatile`. Synchronizing on a random object is not going to do anything for you. And will most likely be slower than `volatile` anyway.

Comment: I agree with others, you need a memory barrier to read the value correctly. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicMarkableReference.html might offer some functions that help in this context.

Comment: I've been looking into `AtomicReference` and noticed the use of `Unsafe`...after some research, this may be exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not correct. The reader of the value would have to synchronize on the same object to read the value, and then, the happens-before principle would apply.

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility):

> An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method entry) of that same monitor. And because the happens-before relation is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that monitor.

Comment: I can't find the source for where I read it, but I was under the impression that any values set within ANY block synchronized on ANY monitor would be written to memory when the montior was released...guess not :p...thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Your current approach is not correct and will not guarantee the visibility of the write. What I suggest is that you definitely use a volatile variable to hold the value and, if volatile reads are truly your concurrent application's proven bottleneck, adapt the design such that each thread reads the volatile value only once and caches it in some thread-local storage. Also note that a thread which starts after a variable has been written is guaranteed to see the write even if it is a plain, non-volatile variable.